# Removing a specific contour line in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, contourf

I'm using contourf to plot values from a 3D matrix, but I want a specific contour not displayed in my plots.

Following is the code I use to plot said matrix.

```
subplot(3,1,1)
contourf(squeeze(u(ja,ia,1)))
[Lu,mu] = contourf(squeeze(u(ja,ia,1)));
ou = mu.LevelStep;
mu.LevelStep = 0.2
clabel(Lu,mu)
title('Model run the u component')
colorbar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the contours you want `contourf` to display using the second input argument:

```
contourf(rand(100)*10,[1,4,7,8]);
```

So you can just specify the contours that you do want, and exclude the ones you don't.